# Verb at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs, verb-agreement

Can we use “verb s/es” at the beginning of a sentence? For example: “It looks good” becomes “looks good” or “goes into the room, he looks shocked” or maybe if you have more examples that can enlighten me better, I will truly appreciate that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

In informal speech we often say, "Seems OK", "Looks good", "Smells delicious", "Sounds lovely" etc.

Does he live here? (if auxiliaries are allowed).

> Was she angry?

> Has he anyone else?

In older English:

> Thinks he to carry her, and live? (Beaumont & Fletcher)

> Stands Scotland where it did? (Shakespeare)

The stage-directions in plays are always abbreviated: "Moves left", "Removes jacket", "Takes glass".